# How can two columns in a SparkSQL dataframe be coalesced?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Spark SQL dataframe that looks like this:

```
df.select("FirstName","F_Name","Dept").show()

FirstName|F_Name|Dept
---------------------
Alfred   |null  |c1
null     |Jarvis|c2
Jeeves   |null  |c1
```

I want to be able to coalesce FirstName and F_Name so that I can have a table that looks like this:

```
Name  |Dept
-----------
Alfred|c1
Jarvis|c2
Jeeves|c1
```

I tried using coalesce as such but didn't work:

```
df.select("coalesec(FirstName,F_Name) as Name","Dept").show()
```

Either PySpark or Scala way of doing this would greatly help.

Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [coalesce](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#coalesce(org.apache.spark.sql.Column...)) function is exactly what you are looking for

```
df.select(coalesce(df.col("FirstName"),df.col("F_Name")).alias("Name"), df.col("Dept")).show()
```